# Adding an empty point to a charts with logarithmic scaling

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm using `C#` `charts` to display/compare some data. I changed the graph scale to `logarithmic` (as my data points have huge differences) but since `logarithmic` scaling doesn't support `zero` values, I want to just add an empty point (or skip a data point) for such cases. I have tried the following but non works and all crashes:

```
if (/*the point is zero*/)
{
    // myChart.Series["mySeries"].Points.AddY(null);
    // or
    // myChart.Series["mySeries"].Points.AddY();
    // or just skip the point
}
```

Is it possible to add an empty point or just skip a point?

Comment: If it is in a loop, can't you just `continue` ?

Comment: It is a loop and I can continue, but that wont add an empty point. I have already labeled my X-axis so if I continue the loop on the next loop I will add a wrong Y value to my X value

Comment: I had the same problem :(

Comment: @shady sherif, if you are still wondering how to do this, I found some answer.

Comment: If you have an answer please post it. It is butter for the community

Comment: @shady sherif, what do you mean '_post it_'?) I've already done that, just before posting my comment. And then I commented here for you to know the problem is solved,)

Comment: Thanks i didn't see the answer

Answer (score 6):

I found two ways to solve the problem.

One is using `double.NaN` (suddenly!):

```
if (myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic && y == 0)
    myChart.Series["mySeries"].Points.AddY(double.NaN);
    // or ...Points.Add(double.NaN)
```

This looks like zero
[image]

And in my case it **didn't** crash with following `SeriesChartType`s:

```
Column, Doughnut, FastPoint, Funnel, Kagi, Pie, Point, Polar, Pyramid, Radar, Renko, Spline, SplineArea, StackedBar, StackedColumn, ThreeLineBreak
```

The other way is a built-in concept of an empty point:

```
if (myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic && y == 0)
    myChart.Series["mySeries"].Points.Add(new DataPoint { IsEmpty = true });
```

This looks like a missing point (a gap):
[image]

And in my case it **didn't** crash with following `SeriesChartType`s:

```
Area, Bar, Column, Doughnut, FastPoint, Funnel, Line, Pie, Point, Polar, Pyramid, Radar, Renko, Spline, SplineArea, StackedArea, StackedArea100, StackedBar, StackedBar100, StackedColumn, StackedColumn100, StepLine, ThreeLineBreak
```

The **2nd approach** feels like the **right** (by design) one. The **1st one** looks like a **hack**, that accidentally appears to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a trick. You obviously have to clear you series. When you start adding points to an empty points collection x-coordinates are generated automatically starting at 1. You can create surrogate x yourself and skip some x-values.

```
int x = 0;
foreach(var y in yValues)
{
    x++;
    if (myChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsLogarithmic && y == 0)
        continue;
    myChart.Series["mySeries"].Points.AddXY(x, y);
}
```

With bar-like chart types it will look like a missing value.

Comment: My upvote for a good point. But what if chart type is `Line`? Then your approach gives something looking like a __repeated__ value, __not__ an empty one.

Comment: @Alex thanks. I admit my solution has weak points. But so does any one. It's up to OP to decide which one to use in the situation to get the best result.